# When Graphics2D.fill() can work 10 times slower in SWT?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, swt, awt

I am investigating the problem, when `Piccolo2D` graphics works much slower when inside `SWT` bridge.

Finally I found, that the code, which works much slower, is the call to [`Graphics2D.fill()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#fill%28java.awt.Shape%29) method. In the case of SWT bridge it works 10 times slower, that in plain Swing.

The probable reason is clipping region.

What are other possible reasons?

And how is it possible to see, that the reason is clipping? The result of `Graphics2D.getClipBounds()` is the same in both case, but it is documented as "user" clipping area. Is it possible to see "device" clipping area?

Comment: A lot of work has been done in Java 7 on the OpenGL path in the rendering pipeline of Swing.  My guess is that SWT talks to a Win32 GDI or other windows graphics interface that doesn't exploit the hardware as well. Certainly a factor of 10 is an easy ratio to see for hardware vs. software rendering primitives.

Comment: How to make sure of it?

Comment: P.S. I was unable to see this slowing in coombination SWT+Swing, but only with three components SWT+Swing+Piccolo2D

Comment: You can write your own fill function.

I think it is because of recursive callbacks this function has.

Comment: SWT is heavyweight. It delegates a lot of the drawing operations to the hardware directly. I ran into a similar issue when trying to draw BufferedImages.

Answer (score 0):

SWT became slower than Swing because it uses proxy to OS widgets. The problem is that the OS part (unmanaged code) communicates very often with the Java code (managed code). This 'transition' (managed to unmanaged and the opposite) is slow because the JVM has to set flags on the system to say whether what the program can access or not (memory, ...).

Whereas Swing mostly stay in the 'managed code' part, and thus can benefit of the JIT optimization for instance.

In another hand, SWT widgets give a better feeling, since the OS manages the drawing, hovering state and so, even if Java code is lagging a little.

Thought, Piccolo2D use lightweight widget, and thus do not have any advantage of SWT :-(